# Problem combining sensors with controller board

Tags: transistors, relay, sensor, controller

I found nice touchless sensors to detect water level and need to incorporate them with a control board that will pump water when the level is low and stop when refilled.

I got it figured out using relays, but if possible I like to do without them (less parts, less could go wrong).

Right now the sensors are triggering mini relays that are operating the controller. Can someone tell me how to modify the controller to connect output from the censors direct? Both controller and sensors are 5 V operated. I presume to replace the relay operating the S2 switch could be easy since the sensor is providing ground when triggered, but S1 needs positive output, right?

[image]

[image]

---

Got it working without using those 2 additional relays but now new problem occurred. The relay driven by the transistor is on when the circuit detects water in the tank, so it would be on most of the time. I need to have it on only when pumping water.
How do I reverse that?
Ideas?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: user332747 - Hi, You posted an "answer" but it still asked for help. As you are the OP, you would only write an answer if you *fully* solved the problem yourself & the topic can be closed *with no more help needed*. If you ask for more advice in an "answer" then it becomes a *question* again! For the Stack Exchange "model" to work, people must not ask for help in an answer - it is supposed to be a clear *solution*. Therefore I have moved your post to become an update in the question. If you make a new final solution, on your own & unrelated to another answer, you can post it as a self-answer.

Comment: Oh, OK, sorry about that and thank you fixing it for me :)